# How many days before the journey 2S type railway tickets are available online?

Tags: online-resources, indian-railways, irctc

How many days before the journey date, 2S (second sitting) type railway tickets are available in the online IRCTC website?

Answer (score 5):

The Indian railway tickets are available **120** days before the journey date in online and ticket counters.

Please refer the official announcement from the IRCTC website:
[Advance Reservation Period (ARP) for booking in trains is increased from 60 days to 120 days w.e.f 1st April, 2015.](https://www.services.irctc.co.in/beta_htmls/arp.html)

Comment: Not sure if this is true because I cant book ticket on train 15060 from DLI to LKU for 60 days later.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question.

If date of journey is more than 10 days then for second sitting it will show like this.

> "Booking not allowed as the Date given is outside Advance Reservation
>   Period"

For second sitting, the online booking is available 10 days before date of journey. Suppose DOJ is 13/01/2017 then they will be available from 03/01/2017. This is my observation only done on IRCTC site.

Comment: Not exactly, Train number 12635 is full of 2S and CC. I can book the ticket for March now itself.

Comment: Hi @Arulkumar I have tried for this train 12757 where it is showing like this. "Booking not allowed as the Date given is outside Advance Reservation Period". Source: Secunderabad JN, Destination: Bellampalii DOJ: More than 10 days from journey

Answer (score -2):

Booking starts at 8:00 AM, 30 days before the journey date.

Comment: Do you have a link? A source? More than 7 words?